# MongoDB index on value of one element and sorted second element

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

I have a set of hundreds of thousands of documents, of type:

```
{
   ...
   "hidden": boolean,
   "created_at": date
   ...
}
```

The main use case is to search for documents where hidden is false, sorted by creation date ascending. The hidden = true documents are the overwhelming majority (something like 99k hidden vs 1k not hidden), and they're all around the place when sorted by my criteria.

My question is, does it make sense here to define an index like `{ hidden: 1, created_at:  1}`? Is there a better way to define an index on an unsorted value of a property and sorted value of another property, or is Mongo smart enough to use that index for the query I described?

And what if I wanted to sort by created_at descending instead? Would the above index still work, or would I need to define a second index in the form of `{hidden: 1, created_at: -1}`?

From my understanding, a generic index on created_at would help in both sorting directions, but I'm confused on how that behavior changes if I expand the same index to cover "hidden", which in theory should not care about sorting order but that I need to sort if I want to combine it with a sorted index on created_at.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { created_at: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { "hidden": false  } }
)
```

1. That way your index size will be smaller and easlily fit in memory since only the 1k not hidden values will be part of the index ...
2. Your created_at field can be used easily to sort in both directions 1 & -1 since is the first field in the compound partial index ...

P.S. Afcourse it is always best to test ...